# Location Tracking bouncing the current location and by default drawing the route

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am tracking the location from user's current location, and I have set the `desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, but there is one issue with drawing route that is without moving device the current location is bouncing and drawing the route. Any solution for that to set the accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLLocationManager()` has `distanceFilter` and `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`.

You can add a `distanceFilter` to "ignore" positions and set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to true.

If you are using location for navigation don't hesitate to use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

Comment: I was done this, but not get accurate results, here is my code - locationManager.delegate = self
         //locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
         locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
         locationManager.distanceFilter = 0
         locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

Comment: If you use a distance filter of 0, your app will get all of the location points, you should try to use a bigger distance filter.

Comment: I was set the distance filter  = 5, but there is no result, can I avoid to set distance filter?